# Hyperledger Explore "Register User" Fail

Tags: hyperledger

Can somebody explain me how the "Register User" function of Hyperledger Explorer works ? Does Affiliation stands for Organization ? Is it designed to create a new user on the network ( including public/priv keys etc ) ? On my side it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 0):

"Register User" not yet fully implemented in the last version ... just need to wait the future one. Question can be closed